# Detecting if an image or shape exists in html5 canvas with a scanned image

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-canvas, object-detection

I'm working with scanned forms (paper documents).
This forms are in html5 canvas.
I have some specific images (logos, shapes, rectangles) that I need to know if exists in html5 canvas.
Note that the images ar similar but not equal.
I'm working with java script
So (finally!) my question is:
Anyone have any idea or know any library to detect if an image exists on html5 canvas with some percentage of accuracy. Code samples with js are welcome.

Comment: Feature Detection is the term you're after. From a long lost vague memory, I think either correlation or convolution are involved.
Anyhoo - here's something to chew on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(computer_vision)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.